# Silverlight 4 accessing WCF Data Services: BeginInvoke frustrations

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, service, begininvoke

I'm attempting to follow a pattern for performing WCF data service queries using the Silverlight 4 beta.  The following is my code:

```
    public CodeTables()
    {
        CodeCountries = new ObservableCollection<dsRealHomes.CodeCountries>();

        dsRealHomes.RealHomesEntities myClient = null;
        myClient = staticGlobals.RealHomesContext();

        object userState = null;


        myClient.BeginExecute<dsRealHomes.CodeCountries>(new Uri("CodeCountries"),
        (IAsyncResult asyncResult) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                 () =>
                 {
                     var test = myClient.EndExecute<dsRealHomes.CodeCountries>asyncResult).ToList();
                 }
             );
        }, userState);
    }
```

This is derived from a number of examples I've come across for WCF data services with silverlight.  Unfortunately no matter how I try to implement the code i end up with the following error on 'Dispatcher.BeginInvoke':

> 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Action)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I have the answer now. It appears that because I was instantiating the BeginInvoke from a class file and not from a UI file (such as a page) that the UI dispatcher was not being used (if that makes any sense).  Using a lead from this article:

http://gen5.info/q/2008/06/25/getting-back-to-the-ui-thread-in-silverlight-2/

I used the propsed UIThread static class and assigned the RootVisual.Dispatcher to it.  Now in my code instead of 'Dispatcher.BeginInvoke' I am using 'UIThread.Run'.  And it works.